# How do I resolve SQL ConnectionString error?

Tags: vb.net, oledb

I have a Form with a DataGridView and a Button. They are interacting with an Access (`.mdb`) database. When the Button is clicked, I want it to update the data in the Table.

I get the following error:

> Value of type 'OleDbConnection' cannot be converted to
> 'SqlConnection'.

My code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1
    Public conn As New OleDbConnection

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim DS As New DataSet
        Dim DT As New DataTable
        DS.Tables.Add(DT)
        Dim objConn As String = "Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = Swiftest.mdb"
        conn.ConnectionString = objConn
        Dim objDA As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblOptions", conn)
        objDA.Fill(DT)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = DT.DefaultView
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim SqlQuery As String = "'UPDATE tblOptions Set fldShow = '1' WHERE fldID = '13'"
        conn.Open()
        Dim com As New SqlCommand(SqlQuery, conn)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks for reading

Comment: Remove this: `Public conn As New OleDbConnection` and this: `Imports System.Data.SqlClient` (not used here), declare the Connection along with an OleDbCommand (not an SqlCommand), both with `Using` statements, so you'll dispose of these objects right away. -- You don't need the DataSet. You may need the `OleDbDataAdapter`, to update the database. Side note: the database path needs to be declared using a full path or using the `|DataDirectory|` setting.

Comment: Hi Jimi, thanks for replying. How do I use the Adapter instead of the dataset?

Comment: [Updating Data Sources with DataAdapters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/updating-data-sources-with-dataadapters). Search SO using the information you find there. Many answers about this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Several of the database objects available is ADO.net have `.Dispose` methods. If an object has a dispose method it may be using unmanaged resources (resources outside the .net framework). These objects need to release these resources and they do this in there dispose methods. Fortunately the .net languages provide `Using...End Using` blocks which will guarentee that `.Dispose` is called even if there is an error.

In view of this create your database objects in the `Sub` or `Function` where they are used so they can be enclosed in `Using` blocks. Note the comma at the end of the connection `Using` line. This indicates that the object on the next line (the command) is included in the same `Using` block.

In your `Form.Load` event, you never used the adapter or the dataset. Just load the datatable.

Open the connection at the last possible moment, directly before the `.Execute...` and close immediately with the `End Using`. In your `Button1.Click` event you open a connection, never execute anything and never close it.

In your update command you provide literals as `String`. Normally, an ID field is an `Integer`. Check you database for the datatype of the fields. If you want to provide values that are not literals use parameters.

```
Private connStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = Swiftest.mdb"

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim DT As New DataTable

    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(connStr),
          cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM tblOptions", conn)
        conn.Open()

        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            DT.Load(reader)
        End Using
    End Using

    DataGridView1.DataSource = DT.DefaultView
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(connStr),
          cmd As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE tblOptions Set fldShow = '1' WHERE fldID = '13'", conn)
        conn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```